# PyGame collision working but sprite being reset - motion not continuing.

Tags: python, pygame

Having trouble with my PyGame experimental game - I'm learning how to work with sprites.

I have been trying to code 'collision' detection between sprites (ball and paddle) and have managed to get the collision detection working but my ball sprite seems to reset its position instead of carrying on. Could anyone take a look and see where my error is?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

#variables, constants, functions
x = 1
y = 1
x_vel = 10
y_vel = 10

bat_x = 1
bat_y = 1
bat_x_vel = 0
bat_y_vel = 0

score = 0

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the ball.
    It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    """
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
        and its x and y position. """
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        # Draw the ellipse
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, (255,0,0), [0,0,width,height], 10)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Instance variables that control the edges of where we bounce
        self.left_boundary = 0
        self.right_boundary = 0
        self.top_boundary = 0
        self.bottom_boundary = 0

        # Instance variables for our current speed and direction
        self.vel_x = 5
        self.vel_y = 5

    def update(self):
        """ Called each frame. """
        self.rect.x += self.vel_x
        self.rect.y += self.vel_y

        if self.rect.right >= self.right_boundary or self.rect.left <= self.left_boundary:
            self.vel_x *= -1

        if self.rect.bottom >= self.bottom_boundary or self.rect.top <= self.top_boundary:
            self.vel_y *= -1


class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the ball.
    It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    """
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
        and its x and y position. """
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        # Draw the rectangle
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (0, 255, 0), [0, 0, width, height], 0)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Instance variables for our current speed and direction
        self.x_vel = 0
        self.y_vel = 0

    def update(self):
        # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
        # as a list of two numbers.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.x_vel
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.y_vel


#initialise ball and paddle
paddle = Paddle(20, 100)
ball = Ball(100,100)

# This is a list of every sprite.
# All blocks and the player block as well.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(ball)
all_sprites_list.add(paddle)
ball_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
ball_sprites_list.add(ball)

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Events code goes here (mouse clicks, key hits etc)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                paddle.y_vel = -3
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                paddle.y_vel = 3

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                paddle.y_vel = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                paddle.y_vel = 0

    # --- Game logic should go here
    # Calls update() method on every sprite in the list
    all_sprites_list.update()

    # collision check
    ball_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(paddle, ball_sprites_list, False)

    # Check the list of collisions.
    for ball in ball_hit_list:
        score +=1
        print(score)

    # --- Clear the screen
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    # --- Draw all the objects
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # render text
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
    label = myfont.render(str(score), 1, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(label, (100, 100))

    # --- Update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please consider simplifying your code to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get faster answers.

Comment: Thanks, found error anyway. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry,

Have found the error.

Didn't set the boundaries of the window properly.

```
# Instance variables that control the edges of where we bounce
self.left_boundary = 0
self.right_boundary = 700
self.top_boundary = 0
self.bottom_boundary = 400
```

Comment: Why not simply using a `Rect`? The values you use seems to describe a rect, so I suggest using the `Rect` class here.